# How do I remove a custom terminal profile from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

How do I delete the custom profile "New 1" as shown in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I'm using Zsh, so I suggest configuration

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "zsh": {
        "path": "/bin/zsh",
        "icon": "star",
        "env": {
        "TESTING_VAR": "abc"
        }
    }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "zsh",
```

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [Configuring profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles) section of the VS Code docs), when you create a custom terminal profile, it adds an entry to your settings.json file:

> The recommended way to create a new profile is to run the **Terminal: Select Default Profile** command and activate the configure button on the right side of the shell to base it on. This will add a new entry to your settings that can be tweaked manually in your `settings.json` file.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
>  "PowerShell -NoProfile": {
>    "source": "PowerShell",
>    "args": ["-NoProfile"]
>  }
> },
> "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
>  "zsh (login)": {
>    "path": "zsh",
>    "args": ["-l"]
>  }
> }
> ```

So open your [User settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) and you'll find the `terminal.integrated.profiles.<OS>` setting with an added entry for your custom profile under your corresponding OS. It is better to open the **settings.json** file directly, or open it from the UI "Edit settings.json":

**settings UI**

[image: settings UI screenshot]

**settings.json**

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "1": {
        "path": "bash"
    }
}
```

(*I'm using a Mac OS so I have it in `.osx`. It gets added correspondingly to `.linux` or `.windows`*)

To remove your custom profile:

1. Simply delete your custom profile (`"1": {...}`) from `terminal.integrated.profiles`
2. **Reload**/**Restart VS Code**

When VS Code reloads/restarts, the removed custom profiles should be gone. (It seems these custom profiles are read and loaded one-time during VS Code startup).

Note though that this only works for custom profiles. For [built-in profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_removing-builtin-profiles), you'll have to set the profile to `null` instead:

> To remove profile entries from the dropdown, set the name of the profile to null. For example, to remove the Git Bash profile on Windows, use this setting:
>
> ```
> "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
>  "Git Bash": null
> }
> ```

Comment: I can't see the custom profile I created anywhere in the settings UI or settings.json but it is still there in the menus.